# How can a partition be full if du does not show it is?

Tags: linux, partitioning, opensuse, opensuse-12.2

On one of my systems, the root partition is full:

```
snip:˜ # df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           11G  9.3G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        744M   36K  744M   1% /dev
tmpfs           751M     0  751M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           751M  296K  751M   1% /run
/dev/sda7        11G  9.3G     0 100% /
tmpfs           751M     0  751M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           751M  296K  751M   1% /var/lock
tmpfs           751M  296K  751M   1% /var/run
tmpfs           751M     0  751M   0% /media
/dev/sda5       151M   39M  104M  28% /boot
/dev/sda8       4.4G  207M  3.3G   6% /home
```

But `du` does not show near 9.3 gigabyte of usage:

```
snip:~ # du /* -s -h
5.2M    /bin
34M /boot
36K /dev
22M /etc
199M    /home
154M    /lib
20M /lib64
0   /media
0   /mnt
0   /opt
0   /proc
7.9M    /root
288K    /run
7.1M    /sbin
0   /selinux
756K    /srv
0   /sys
0   /tmp
1.6G    /usr
1.1G    /var
```

It only accounts for about 3 gigabytes.

- How can that be?
- Where should I look for the remaining 6+ gigabytes of used gigabytes?

I'm using openSUSE 12.2:

```
snip:~ # cat /etc/SuSE-release
openSUSE 12.2 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12.2
CODENAME = Mantis
```

Comment: Did you unlink any files? (e.g. deleting/clearing a log file while it is still in use. Thus removing it from the directory listing while it still occupies disk space?)

Comment: Other idea: Did you use space in a directory on /, and then mounted another directory on top of that, thus masking the old files?

Comment: @Hennes no, and no. I'm baffled: I've never seen anything like this happen on a linux system before.

Comment: Lets nuance the previous comment @Hennes: I've not done consciously. Can there be any subsystem that might have done this?

Comment: It is easily tested by rebooting (to free unlinked files) and then booting into single user mode. The second can also be done in other ways, e.g. `tellinit  1`, maybe `shutdown` without -h -r (not sure about that one on linux, on BSD that drops you to runlevel 1), `umount -a`. Or just looking at what is mounted and testing that.

Comment: Your mounts might simply be "hiding" a lot of stuff underneath them.

Comment: I'm going to boot into single user mode and see what is going on.

Comment: @Hennes I booted a rescue system from CD as it would not come up properly in single user mode because root was full. From the rescue system, I did `mount /dev/sda7 /mnt`, then `chroot /mnt`, then `du -s -h *` again: virtually the same result: the `du` results don't add up to the `df` result.

Comment: Any luck with an fsck (before mounting RW) ?. Also, feel free to add that to the post so we can delete the comments.

Comment: I found it through the openSUSE forums: it uses btrfs and snapshots. So the snapshots take up a lot of space. And I need to find out a way to delete old snapshots. https://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/install-boot-login/490199-how-can-partition-full-if-du-does-not-show.html#post2583491

Comment: I think I found it: http://www.nrtm.org/index.php/2012/03/13/the-joys-of-btrfs-and-opensuse-or-no-space-left-on-device/

Comment: @Hennes found it and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**First some background information**

If you have [btrfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) on your root file system on http://www.opensuse.org/en/, then two things will happen:

1. openSUSE will automagically start using [snapper](http://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Snapper) to take [snapshots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_%28computer_storage%29) of your root file system.
2. the snapshots will take up diskspace that [du](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_%28Unix%29) doesn't show

This means that you will run out of disk space sooner than you'd expect. So the recommendation (not in the docs) is to [make partitions that use snapshots twice as large as you normally would](https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/introduction-system-rollbacks-btrfs-and-snapper-sles-11-sp2/).

I have not found a way to show the size per snapshot or the total size of all snapshots.

So you have to monitor your free disk space with `df` or this btrfs specific command for the root (`/`) file system:

```
btrfs filesystem df /
```

**Cleaning up snapper snapshots**

Thanks to [NerdyRoom™ » The joys of btrfs and OpenSuSE – or “no space left on device”.](http://www.nrtm.org/index.php/2012/03/13/the-joys-of-btrfs-and-opensuse-or-no-space-left-on-device/) 
I found out the easiest way to delete older snapshots that you might want to delete (and you have to when you run out of disk space).

First run `snapper list` to see the sequence number of snapshots that are there.

From that list, select a reasonable lower and upper bound of snapshots to delete.

Then run this with the lower (`1`) and upper (`3656`) bound:

```
for i in `seq 1 3656`; do snapper delete $i; done
```

*Edit 20161212:*

An anonymous user suggested an edit to make this shorter. I agree, as the above can be done shorter as per [snapper man page](http://snapper.io/manpages/snapper.html):

```
snapper delete 1-3656
```