# After I type login it back to login immediately

Tags: login, opensuse

After a failed try to update a software using a .ymp file (IIRC the extension of file) my OS started claimed about no left space on hard drive but a lot of free space is available. So I reboot the system to try solve this error but instead of I get another error on login: when I type the password, it accepts, but the system is not up and back to the login immediately. The same problem as this guy (but I also root user (the one which I'm logged right now) I just have one user in this system that I can't login in) I've tried to run the commands as answer suggests althrough it ran without error it changes nothing the login error. If it's relevant, here's my open suse version:

```
# cat /etc/SuSE-release
openSUSE 12.1 (i586)
VERSION = 12.1
CODENAME = Asparagus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `/` and `/home` on different partitions and `/home` is full. You can still login as root because root's home is `/root`.

You can use `df -hT` to check the space left on your partitions and their type. Depending on your partitions and the filesystem on them, `df` could report more space than you can actually use (if you are using btrfs for instance, [like other OpenSUSE users](https://superuser.com/questions/642589/how-can-a-partition-be-full-if-du-does-not-show-it-is), even without "snapshots" btrfs uses space for metadata).

(The first version saying you ran out of space when downloading something was better, and here we don't know who "this guy" is or what commands you ran.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your shell initialization files are outputting something off-putting to the GUI stack.  Move them to the side temporarily (mkdir .rcarchive && mv .bash_profile .bashrc .alias .profile .kshrc .rcarchive/), then try again.